How to add additional fields in model serializer in django ModelViewSet?
Cart Serializer classs
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    menuitem = MenuItemSerializer(read_only=True)
    price = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='calculate_price')
    menuitem_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'menuitem', 'quantity',
                  'unit_price', 'price', 'menuitem_id', 'user_id']
        validators = [
            validators.UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=MenuItem.objects.all(),
                fields=('id',),
                message="Menuitem should be unique in this curt"
            ),
            validators.UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=User.objects.all(), fields=('id'), message="User should be unique")
        ]

    def calculate_price(self, item: Cart):
        print(item.unit_price * item.quantity)
        return item.unit_price * item.quantity

add_cart method in CartItemsViewSet class
 @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def add_cart(self, request, pk=None):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            user = request.user
        else:
            return Response('User is not authenticated', 403)
        # print(request.data)
        # print(request.user.id)
        # user_id = user.id
        # menuitem_id = request.data['menuitem_id']
        # quantity = request.data['quantity']
        # unit_price = request.data['unit_price']
        # id = request.data['id']
        # pack_data = {'user_id': user_id, 'menuitem_id': menuitem_id,
        #              'quantity': quantity, 'unit_price': unit_price, 'id': id}

        serializer = serializers.CartSerializer(
            data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            print(serializer.validated_data)
            serializer.save(user_id=user.id)
            return Response('Item is added successfully.', 201)

Cart Model
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    menuitem = models.ForeignKey(MenuItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(),
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('menuitem', 'user')

I want to implement a login user add a menu item to their cart. But the problem is that I do not add additional field 'user_id' when save the table with the serializer the following error message has been shown.
{
"user_id": [
"This field is required."
]
}


Any reason for printing and returning the same expression in calculate_price?

Also did you separate your viewsets logic from your serializes? Everything seems jumbled together making it harder to read


Send user_id to the payload as well.  2nd. Remove it from serializer or add user after serializer.save() manually


The reason the drf raises that error, even though you pass the user.id to the save method, is the error raised by method is_valid that is run before the save method and the key user is not set in request.data.
To pass the logged-in user to the serializer you can use this serializer field:
user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

This field will get the user from the request by itself.
Hint: I think you should revise your model and unique constraints (especially constraints in serializer)
Hint: The HTTP status code for not authentication is 401 or if you want to return status code 403 the message should be something else e.g. permission denied

user_id should be read-only, otherwise it expects to find the data in the request, so:
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # …
    user_id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    # …
You write the user_id through the .save() of the serializer:
serializer.save(user_id=user.id)
